# How I can write calendar events to google web calendar?

Tags: java, android, web, calendar

I try write events to google calendar in the web, but this code write my events to locale android calendar only. I need write events to both calendars. Please, help.

```
public void writeCalendar() {
        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        event.put("calendar_id", mCalendarId);    
        event.put("title", "Beaty and fun");
        event.put("description", "This is a simple test for calendar api");
        event.put("dtstart", System.currentTimeMillis());
        event.put("dtend", System.currentTimeMillis() + 1800*1000);
        event.put("allDay", 0);
        event.put("eventStatus", 0);
        event.put("visibility", 0);
        event.put("transparency", 0);
        event.put("hasAlarm", 0);
        Uri l_eventUri;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8 ) {
            l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
        } else {
            l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
        }
        Uri eventUri =    Resources.instance().getActivity()
                 .getContentResolver().insert(l_eventUri, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to authenticate the user and communicate with Google using the [Google Calendar Api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/).

To add to both you would have to have 2 separate actions for each calendar, native and Google, **or** if the user has Google calendar downloaded on their device then adding to the Google calendar will sync with their Google Calendar App on their device and as such satisfy both your criteria.